# Excel Files in SharePoint Designer

Tags: excel

I added excel file (.xlsx) in SharePoint Designer. These files appear as notepad in SharePoint Designer.

[image]

I want to these files appear as excel file. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Check file type association

Comment: Why do you care what the icon in SPD is? You won't try to open them from SPD, so what does it matter?

Comment: There are pictures in the excel file. These pictures don't appear   to excel in WebPart. I think not appear to have registered as notepad. @teylyn

Comment: What are you doing in SharePoint Designer with Excel files? SharePoint Designer is for editing SharePoint pages and customising SharePoint sites. You cannot do anything with Excel files in SharePoint Designer. Excel web parts cannot display embedded objects like pictures. SharePoint Designer cannot change that. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

When you export the file, try changing the defult view settings to data sheet view within your library or list ( in settings). Then it has the cells and columns of excel, and you can edit via sharepoint or excel.

Comment: And how is this related to SharePoint Designer?